# smart groups and relations

Tags: contacts, relationships, smartgroups

I want to build a smart group with 3 relationships. Is it possible to search for 3 relationships in one step?

I have tried with advanced search, search builder and custom search. But I havent found any solution.

I have CiviCRM 4.5.2

thx

Comment: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8315/how-to-search-active-relationships-e-g-during-past-year#comment9797_9803

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to create a smart group per relationship type and then another smart group that contains all 3 groups.

I am not sure why in advanced search you can only select one relationship type and not more at the same time.

Comment: thx.
I use advanced search as
- search
- advanced search
- at relationstype I choose the relationstype

how you can choose more than one relationstype?

Comment: thx. I use advanced search as - search - advanced search - at relationstype I choose the relationstype 

how you can choose more than one relationstype?

Comment: Just choose one, turn the results into "smart group 1", repeat it for the two other relationship types. Then choose the 3 smart groups in advanced search and turn the results of those in your final smart group.